# How to list all detected cameras in firefox (offline without a website)?

Tags: firefox, browser, webcam, camera

How can I get firefox to show me a list of all the webcams that it can see?

I do *not* want to use a website. I want something native in firefox that I can use offline without visiting a third party service.

How can I enumerate all of the webcams that my web browser can see?

Comment: Try the add-on [MyIPCam for IP cameras](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/myipcam-for-ip-cameras/).

Comment: Are you specifically looking for camera devices local to the computer the browser is running on, or visible over the network FROM the computer your browser is running on?

Comment: I am specifically looking to enumerate the list of camera devices that are local to the computer, which I would later be able to authorize a website to be able to access via the browser permissions.